# Многопоточность в python не в отдельных функциях

Tags: python, многопоточность, циклы

Нужно каким то образом запустить цикл который будет работать параллельно с основной программой.

нашел такой пример использования многопоточности, но тут работают параллельно именно две функции

```
from threading import Thread

def prescript(thefile, num):
    with open(thefile, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(num):
            if num > 500:
                f.write('МногоБукв\n')
            else:
                f.write('МалоБукв\n')
                
thread1 = Thread(target=prescript, args=('f1.txt', 200,))
thread2 = Thread(target=prescript, args=('f2.txt', 1000,))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

а у меня есть основной цикл который должен выполняться каждую секунду и проверять значение переменной которая может меняться, но при значении этой переменной = 100, должен параллельно начаться таймер который после 30 секунд будет повторная проверка переменной а, и если а == 100 выведет слово YES.

```
while True:
    a = check_something()
    if a == 100:
        #тут начинается что то по типу sleep. и через какое то время если переменная a не поменялась то выведет YES
        b = custom_timer(time = 30) # custom_timer это функция с циклом внутри который ждёт 30 секунд а затем return a
        if b == 100:
            print("YES")
```

хочу реализовать custom_timer() вот так:

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
s.enter(5, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Вопрос в том как реализовать что вторая функция таймер будет запускаться параллельно с основным циклом и основной цикл не будет ждать ruturn'a в функции таймер

Comment: А в чем проблема обернуть все в потоки? в принципе 2-3 потока получается (а не 100+) вполне нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения Вашей задачи Вам надо изучить модуль `asyncio`!

Для конкрентного Вашего случая нужно использовать [asyncio.wait_for](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouts)

P.S. Я написал очень примерный код, и если задача изменится, тогда и код очень сильно придётся изменить!

Примерный код:

```
import asyncio

async def do_something():
    return 'Какой-то результат функции'

async def task(function, value):
    while True:
        result = await function
        if result == value:
            return result

async def main():
    await task(do_something(), 100)
    try:
        result = await asyncio.wait_for(
            task(do_something(), 100),
            timeout=30.0
        )
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('Время вышло!')
        ...
    else:
        print(result)
        ...

await main() # Это можно только, если `python3 -m asyncio` в консоли
```